# CS0579: Duplicate 'global::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute'

Tags: azure-devops, dotnet-core-pack

I am trying to build several c# netstandard2.0 dlls and one netcoreapp3.1 application in DevOps

AssemblyInfo.cs for the .exe contains the following
[image: AssemblyInfo]

I can build on my pc.

However the build in DevOps fails with the error

```
 (CoreCompile target) -> 
         obj\Release\netcoreapp3.1\.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs(4,12): error CS0579: Duplicate 'global::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute' attribute
```

THe task in DevOps is

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: pack
    packagesToPack: '**/SBD.*.csproj'
    versioningScheme: byPrereleaseNumber
    majorVersion: '$(Major)'
    minorVersion: '$(Minor)'
    patchVersion: '$(Patch)'
```

Comment: What if we set this msbuild property to false in your csproj's propertyGroup ? `<GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error comes from the auto-generated file `.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs`, I think it has something to with your custom `AssemblyInfo.cs` file.

For `.net core`(new SDK fprmat) project, it doesn't contain the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file by default like `.net framework` (old legacy format). Instead we can set those values in its project file, and it will generate the `xx.AssemblyAttributes.cs` and `ProjectName.AssemblyInfo.cs` for us. I assume there's conflict between your custom `AssemblyInfo.cs` and the auto-generated files.

So you need to set `<GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>` to use your custom `AssemblyInfo.cs` file. Check the [similar ticket](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/9781) in Github/Dotnet-SDK.

Comment: I did have it set to false already so I just deleted AssemblyInfo.cs

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me;

I commented(removed) <*TargetFramework>* property in one of the .cproj's files.